# Allowing users to enter HTML - is this wise?

Tags: html, validation, code-injection

My site allows people (anyone with a free account) to enter text.  Up till now, I've been stripping out HTML tags etc. to ensure that they can't enter anything malicious.  Now, however, the client has asked whether it would be possible to allow the users to enter html.

The thinking behind this is that some users may wish to add more complex things, such as forms. Whatever they enter is displayed on another page, later - so they may want a form which other people can complete and submit.

My question is, what are the risks with this? Obviously I would escape characters to cut the risk of injection attacks, but what else do I need to be aware of?

Or is this so risky that I shouldn't do it at all?

Comment: If forms in particular are an actual suggested use case you need to think about where the forms can be submitted to - just a form on an html page doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 2):

There are many risks - [XSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) being the best known.

If you escape characters, then HTML will not be displayed (instead of a link you will see `<a href="http://example.com">link</a>`, for example).

Allowing HTML is a safe manner is *very* difficult.

Consider using something like the markdown editor used here on StackOverflow - [wmd-new](http://code.google.com/p/wmd-new/).

Answer (score 1):

One nit-picky bit...

> to **help** ensure that they can't enter anything malicious

Never assume your security is complete :)  Now, on to an actual answer...

---

Your biggest security concern here would be [Cross-site Scripting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting).

This bit is what I find particularly troubling:

> they may want a form which other people can complete and submit

Submit to what?  Are they also designing server-side functionality somehow?  Or are they writing forms to submit to some external resource?  That sounds risky.

Then you get into things like `script` tags.  Very malicious things can be done here.  And if the users are savvy enough to craft their own HTML forms (by hand? or is a tool being used?) to submit data to other resources, they're probably crafty enough to write some JavaScript.

Simple markup effects can be achieved with [editors designed for that](http://markitup.jaysalvat.com/home/).  But forms are a whole new ballgame.  This sounds really risky.